# Repeating number in java to next line

Tags: java, if-statement, file-io

I have a Java program that reads from a file like such

6 fun. 3 hello 10 <> 2 25 4 wow!

The number represents how many times the word will be repeated so output would be
fun.fun.fun.fun.fun.fun.

```
hellohellohello

<><><><><><><><><><> 

2525

wow!wow!wow!wow!
```

However, mine is printing all on one line

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Words {
   public static void main(String[] args)
     throws FileNotFoundException {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("aa1234.txt"));
     printStrings(input);  
   }

   public static void printStrings(Scanner input) {
     while (input.hasNext)) {
        int times = input.nextInt();
        String word = input.next(); 
        for (int i = 1; i <= times; i++) {  
           System.out.print(word);
        }  
     }
  }
}
```

I've been playing around with input.nextLine() and whatnot, but don't understand how to get to the next line after it prints the repeated words. Help?

Comment: Using System.out.println() puts each word on it's own line. I want repeated words to be on the same line.

Comment: Okay, so the println goes outside of the for loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.out.print("\n")` to print a line end.

Like this :

```
while (input.hasNext)) {
    int times = input.nextInt();
    String word = input.next(); 
    for (int i = 1; i <= times; i++) {  
       System.out.print(word);
    }  
    System.out.print("\n");
 }
```

You can also use the `System.out.println()` to print a line and automatically append a line end. For example, build the string before print it :

```
 while (input.hasNext)) {
    int times = input.nextInt();
    String word = input.next();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= times; i++) {  
       builder.append(word);
    }  
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
 }
```

Notice the use of [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), much more faster and consuming less memory than a classical string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= times; i++) {  
           System.out.print(word);
} 
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

print one new line after printing all the same words in one line.

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= times; i++) {  
       System.out.print(word);
    } 
    System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

make your function like below

```
public static void printStrings(Scanner input) {
 while (input.hasNext)) {
    int times = input.nextInt();
    String word = input.next(); 
    for (int i = 1; i <= times; i++) {  
       System.out.print(word);
    }  
   System.out.println();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

mine is printing all on one line

**Solution:**

Because you have used `System.out.print()`, using that it will print everything on the same line. If you would want to have a line break then use **`System.out.println()`**

Answer (score 0):

Use System.out.println to print the word on separate lines:

[System.out.println(data)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out)

Answer (score 0):

Print a new line after the inner for loop. Something like this

```
while (input.hasNext()) 
{
   int times = input.nextInt();
   String word = input.next(); 
   for (int i = 1; i <= times; i++) {  
   System.out.print(word);
   }  
   System.out.println();
}
```